# Java - Trident animation library - Reflect interpolation when container resizes

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am quite new to the `Trident Animation Library`, but I managed to use this for my animation and it works really good.

My requirment is to basically animate a `JComponent` from one of the corners of the container to the middle of the container.

Below is my pseudo code

```
this.setLayout(null);    
JButton button =  new JButton();
button.setLocation(new Point (0,0));
Point center =  new Point(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(notification.getComponent());
timeline.addPropertyToInterpolate("location", button .getLocation(), center );
timeline.setDuration(1000);
timeline.play();
```

Now when my container resizes the center of the container changes. 
For e.x: If inital center of container was (100,100) and after the container resizes new center  is (200,200).

Is there any way that I can reflect the new center while interpolation so that the component moves to (200, 200) instead of (100, 100)? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first things that pops into my mind:

At the start store the current window / panel size. At every timeline 'tick' check to see if the current window / panel size is different from the one you started out with (ie. the panel has resized). If it has resized stop the current timeline and create a new timeline with a new path based on the new panel center.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have just once question in the solution given by you. The timeline duration is a predefined value. So the 1000ms in timeline.setDuration(1000) is predefined. Now if I stop the running timeline and create a new timeline each time the container resizes, how will i track the elapsed time, so that each time the resize happens, i can pass "totaltime-elapsedtime" to my new timeline duration. Also if the conztiner resizes too frequently, is it a good idea to stop and create new timelines. Will it effect the performance of the application too drastically?

Comment: As you suggested "totaltime-elapsedtime" seems like a good idea. I would suggest you write a [Compoment Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html) to only recreate the timeline when the user is done resizing the Window / Panel (ie. ignoring all the small steps in between during the resize). As for performance there is only one way to find out: Try it :-)